# Check if file line starts with a character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read some files with Python that contain certain data I need.

The structure of the files is like this:

> NAME : a280
>
> COMMENT : drilling problem (Ludwig)
>
> TYPE : TSP
>
> DIMENSION: 280
>
> EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D
>
> NODE_COORD_SECTION
>
> 1 288 149
>
> 2 288 129
>
> 3 270 133
>
> 4 256 141
>
> 5 256 157
>
> 6 246 157
>
> 7 236 169
>
> 8 228 169
>
> 9 228 161

So, the file starts with a few lines that contain data I need, then there are some random lines I do NOT need, and then there are lines with numerical data that I do need. I read everything that I need to read just fine.

However, my problem is that I cannot find a way to bypass the random number of lines that are sandwiched between the data I need. The lines from file to file can be 1, 2 or more. It would be silly to hardcode some `f.readline()` commands in there to bypass this.

I have thought of some regular expression to check if the line is starting with a string, in order to bypass it, but I'm failing.

In other words, there can be more lines like "NODE_COORD_SECTION" that I don't need in my data.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you give some examples of what a valid line is and what an invalid line is?

Comment: How do you know if you need the line or not?

Comment: Pardon me, you are right, i should have been more specific. I edited the opening post. (regular tsp files from benchmarks you can find online)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply check if every line is valid (stuff you need) and if it is not, you just skip it. For example:

```
line_list = line.split()
if line_list[0] not in ['NAME', 'COMMENT', 'TYPE', ...]:
    break
if len(line_list) != 3:
    break
if len(line_list) == 3 and (type(line_list[0]) != int or type(line_list[1]) != int or type(line_list[2]) != int):
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you add some format to the "lines of your file" and if you showed some code, but her's what I would try.

I would first define a list of strings containing an indication of a valid line, then I would split the current line into a list of strings and check if the first element corresponds to any of the elements in a list of valid strings.

In case the first string doesn't corresponds to any of the strings in the list of valid strings, I would check if the first element is an integer, and so on...

```
current_line = 'LINE OF TEXT FROM FILE'
VALID_WORDS = ['VALID_STR1','VALID_STR2','VALID_STR3']

elems = current_line.split(' ')

valid_line = False
if elems[0] in VALID_WORDS:
    # If the first str is in the list of valid words, 
    # continue...
    valid_line = True
else if len(elems)==3:
    # If it's not in the list of valid words BUT has 3 
    # elements, check if it's and int
    try:
        valid_line = isinstance(int(elems[0]),int)
    except Exception as e:
        valid_line = False
if valid_line:
    # Your thing
    pass
else:
    # Not a valid line
    continue
```